# Увеличить корневой раздел / linux

Tags: диск, раздел, linux

В gparted у меня в / осталось свободно 800Мб с 20Гб, я уверен, что там полно мусора.

Проделывал я такие команды:

```
-sudo apt-get clean all

-sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Answer (score 1):

Поищите у себя в репозитории програму filelight. Она умеет красиво показывать размеры папок. Она поможет.